# Baker-Campbell formula

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

If $$ B a B^† = a\cos(\theta)+ib\sin(\theta)$$
then can I write
$$B a^n B^† = [{a\cos(\theta)+ib\sin(\theta)}]^{n} ?$$

where $B = B=e^{i\theta(a^\dagger b+b^\dagger a)}$

This is my calculation for $B a B^†$

$B a B^†= a+\theta[(a^\dagger)b+(b^\dagger) a),a]+ (\theta)^2/2[(a^\dagger)b+(b^\dagger) a[(a^\dagger)b+(b^\dagger) a),a]]$
$=a\cos(\theta)+ib\sin(\theta)$

Comment: It would help if you provide more information. Where does $\theta$ come from?

Comment: B=eθ((a†)b+(b†)a)

Comment: Note \cos and \sin are valid commands in LaTeX.

Comment: I agree Vishaka. Thanks for the info

Comment: I suggest thinking about what the inverse of $B$ is.

Comment: Did you mean $B=e^{i\theta(a^\dagger b+b^\dagger a)}$ (`B=e^{i\theta(a^\dagger b+b^\dagger a)}`)? If so, please reflect that in an edit. Since $(e^X)^\dagger=e^{X^\dagger}$ (as you can prove with e.g. a Taylor series), if that *is* what you meant $B^\dagger=B^{-1}$ allows for an easy proof of $Ba^nB^\dagger=(BaB^\dagger)^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$B$ is unitary, hence $B^{\dagger}B = I = BB^{\dagger}$.

Let us now compute $[B a B^{\dagger}]^{n}$. First consider the case $n=2$.

$$ [B a B^{\dagger}]^{2} = B a B^{\dagger}BaB^{\dagger} = Ba^{2}B^{\dagger}. $$

No assume that for $n=k$

$$ [B a B^{\dagger}]^{k} =  Ba^{k}B^{\dagger}. $$

Finally multiplying the kth case by $BaB^{\dagger}$ we get the following.

$$[B a B^{\dagger}]^{k} BaB^{\dagger}=  Ba^{k}B^{\dagger}BaB^{\dagger} = Ba^{k+1}B^{\dagger}. $$

By induction we conclude that
\begin{equation}
[BaB^{\dagger}]^{n} = Ba^{n}B^{\dagger}   (1).
\end{equation}

If $BaB^{\dagger} = a\cos(\theta)+ib\sin{\theta}$ then (1) yields the result you are after. i.e.
$$[a\cos(\theta)+ib\sin{\theta}]^{n} =  Ba^{n}B^{\dagger}.$$